# .NET Sand boxing HTTP connections

Tags: c#, .net, http

Basically I have a requirement to connect to an http streaming API in my app - it works fine, but what I want to do is to connect to multiple instances of this API for different accounts with the streaming provider. For whatever reason this doesn't work as the connections interfere with each other, however if I run multiple instances of the app separately, each connecting to the streaming API for a different account, then it is fine.

So I wanted to know what the best way would be to isolate / sandbox these connections so they might work within the same app. I know it is possible to use separate AppDomains but I wondered if anyone might suggest a better/easier strategy.

Comment: Hello! You need to provide code, which reproduces the problem of "connections interfering with each other" to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Thanks yeah I see your point but in this case the code isn't relevant, as there is no "problem to diagnose" as such, it works perfectly fine, but just doesn't work connecting to multiple logins within same app, just as i'd expect really .. same way you cant login to two Facebook sessions on the same chrome instance. So the question is best way of isolating http connections so they don't know anything about each other. Essentially is there a better way than using separate App Domains?